# Concatenate string with variable

Tags: handlebars.js

In my Handlebar `tmp.hbs` template, I use my custom registered `a` helper as such

```
<p>{{a "this is a message by the author"}}</p>
```

which returns

```
 <p>THIS is A message BY the AUTHOR</p>
```

Now I need to make the message dynamic. Basically, I need to add at the end the value of the `{{name}}` variable so the output is (with `name: 'pippo'`)

```
<p>THIS is A message BY pippo</p>
```

Is there a way, if any, to concatenate a string with a variable to use as the single parameter for a helper?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way. `"yourstring{{variable}}"`

```
"/book/borrow/{{_id}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use concatenating helper. When you pass arguments to the helper `a`, you can call another helper `b` on them by enclosing them within `()`, like:

```
{{a (b arg1 arg2)}}
```

```js
var source = $("#template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
  "authors": [
    { "name": "Pippo", "message": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { "name": "Adam", "message": "amet sit dolor ipsum lorem" }
  ]
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('a', function(message, options) {

  return message;

});

Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function () {

    var result = "";

    for(var i in arguments) {
        result += (typeof arguments[i] === "string" ? arguments[i] : "") + " ";
    }
 
    return result;

});

$('body').append(template(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

{{#each authors}}
<p>{{a (concat this.message this.name)}}</p>
{{/each}}


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is I need to use the `a` helpers in other places, with different input strings. Thus, it would be better if I can pass to it a single string.

Comment: Thanks, I feel I have been very clear, but probably I'm wrong. Let me try to rephrase the problem. Is there a way, if any, to concatenate a string with a variable to use as the single parameter for a helper?

Comment: Thanks that just work. It would be great if I could pass to `concat` an arbitrary number of values.